# Which Characters have to be percent-encoded for a URI?

Tags: vb.net, networking, ftp, uri, urlencode

Which characters have to be percent-encoded to have a valid network address? I want to escape all invalid chars, which are reserved like the Hash("#") Character. My goal is to download Files through a Webclient on my FTP-Server.

Thank you very much.

```
Webclient.DownloadFile(FTPObject.FullPath, Path)
```

The error message I've got through the Download File Call was a System.Net.WebException; Errorcode (550) ~ File Not Found.

This was for the Case I didn't percent-encode the Hash.

```
../Test[#][Acoustic Version].mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a literal answer to your question, see:
[Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1856785/850848)

---

Taken literally, your question should be closed as a duplicate.

But as you use VB.NET, the correct answer is not to implement the encoding manually, but use the built-in .NET functionality.

- See [Encoding parameters for a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5095351/850848)
- Or even better, see [How to reliably build a URL in C# using the parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134898/850848)